# A question on Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $g$ be a measurable function on $[0,1]$. Suppose that $g$ is finite almost everywhere and let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure. Then for any $\epsilon >0$, there is a polynomial 
$h$, such that $$ \mu\left(\{x: |g(x)-h(x)|>\epsilon \}\right) < \epsilon.$$

Well, I know that there is a continuous function, say, $f(x)$ such that $|g(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ except on a set of measure less than $\epsilon.$  Now, since polynomials are a continuous functions, can I take $h(x)=f(x)$, and thus proving the above? If not, how to I go about proving it?

Comment: No, that wouldn't immediately follow; but, maybe use [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Weierstrass_approximation_theorem)

Comment: @DavidMitra: How do I use it, since the theorem says that for all $x\in [0,1],|g(x)-h(x)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: That's fine; it's just more than you need.

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing at the outset guarantees that the $f$ you wind up with is a polynomial. [The Weierstrass approximation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Weierstrass_approximation_theorem) however does.

First choose a continuous function $f$ such that $|g(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon/2$ for all $x\in[0,1]\setminus A$ where the  measure of $A$ is less than $\epsilon$.  Then use the aforementioned theorem to find a polynomial $p$ such that $|f(x)-p(x)|<\epsilon/2$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Then $p$ is the desired polynomial.

Comment: So If I get you correctly, I'd have to show that $|g(x)-p(x)|<\epsilon$ and that'll be it?

Comment: @Joe Yes. Just use the triangle inequality.